# How to get the files occupying more size (top 10 files)

Tags: linux

We have a parent directory called "/admin". Inside admin directory we have 100 child directories inside admin like "/admin/a" , "/admin/b" , "/admin/a/Source" ....

We have a find command as below

```
 find /admin -type f -exec du {};

 full command: find /admin -type f -exec du {}; 2>/user/arya/file.txt|sort -rn|head -10 > /user/arya/top10_file.txt
```

This command is taking huge time more than 5-6 hours to give the output ..

Is there any way we can write the command and get the output much faster and get the top 10-20 files occupying huge space.. ?

Please suggest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution to your problem with `find` and `du`

```
find /admin -type f -exec du -a {} + | sort -n -r | head -n 10
```

[`find`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/find.html) and [`du`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/du.html) are both Unix standard tools.

Supplying `{} +` tells `find` to apply the `du` command to several files at the same time; `{};` will apply the `du` command to each file at a time.

Comment: Thanks @Paulo.. Can you help me to understand by adding "-a {} + " & "sort -n -r " what may be the difference ? Please please

Comment: @Arya See my updated answer.

Comment: That is different of the problem that is stated in the question. Please ask a different question.

Comment: Tome.. Can we get user name who updated the file and time in this command ?

Answer (score 1):

By using `printf` in `find`,

```
find /admin -type f -printf '%s %p\n'| sort -nr | head -10
```

- `%s` size of the file in bytes.
- `%p` file name.

Comment: Is there any way to get the created user and file size in mb/gb